# .Net Google Map Ctrl Add to Our Web Page

Tags: .net, asp.net, google-maps

I am Try to add Google Map Control in My Web Page ...But I got Error Google Object Does not Exist Current context [Are u Missing Assembly Reference??] ..so pl z any one Help Me...

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Can you at least use actual words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is simple you haven't added the Refrence of the Library and/or Not set the `using` for the namespaces.

If you are using GoogleMap Control from Codeplex i think you need to use namespace `Artem.GoogleMap.Web` and others. Look in their documentation for help http://googlemap.codeplex.com/documentation